# Sanity Check - Result set different after breaking up case expression in where clause into different selects w/union all

Tags: sql-server, union, query-refactor

I'm back again with more dumb questions. This time I am dealing with refactoring a single select with nested case expressions in the where clause. I'm trying to optimize this, and in attempting to do so, I broke up the query into multiple selects w/ union alls. This does run quite a bit faster, but now I'm seeing more rows return than before, and this does not seem to be due to duplicate rows.

There is more to this query, like creating the temp tables, etc. However, as far as I can tell, that has not had an effect on the result set. I have been able to determine that the second select of the refactored query (much of which is omitted because it is repetitive) is pulling in more results than before.

So, where did I go wrong when pulling this apart? How does my new query/WHERE clause(s) differ from the original? I super appreciate your help in advance.

/*Original*/

```
select
   /*some columns*/
from 
  #SmallerRange IPS
  inner join #LargerRange V on V.AccountNumber !=IPS.AccountNumber and V.InOrOut = IPS.InOrOut and V.LocNum = IPS.LocNum
WHERE 
  CASE 
    WHEN IPS.InOrOut = 'I' THEN
      CASE 
      WHEN IPS.EntryDateTime = V.EntryDateTime AND IPS.ExitDateTime = V.ExitDateTime AND IPS.ProgramID = V.ProgramID THEN 1
      WHEN IPS.EntryDateTime = V.EntryDateTime AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate AND IPS.ProgramID = V.ProgramID THEN 1
      WHEN IPS.EntryDateTime = V.EntryDateTime AND IPS.ExitDateTime = V.ExitDateTime AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate THEN 1
      WHEN IPS.ProgramID = V.ProgramID AND IPS.ExitDateTime = V.ExitDateTime AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate THEN 1
      WHEN IPS.Name = V.Name AND IPS.Name <> 'N/A' AND IPS.ExitDateTime = V.ExitDateTime AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate THEN 1
      ELSE 0 
    END
    WHEN IPS.InOrOut = 'O' THEN
      CASE 
      WHEN IPS.ProgramID = V.ProgramID AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate AND IPS.DropbyDateTime = V.DropbyDateTime THEN 1
      WHEN IPS.ProgramID = V.ProgramID AND IPS.DropbyDateTime = V.DropbyDateTime AND IPS.ARRVLTIME = V.ARRVLTIME THEN 1
      WHEN IPS.ProgramID = V.ProgramID AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate AND IPS.ARRVLTIME = V.ARRVLTIME THEN 1
      WHEN IPS.DropbyDateTime = V.DropbyDateTime AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate AND IPS.ARRVLTIME = V.ARRVLTIME THEN 1
      WHEN IPS.DropbyDateTime = V.DropbyDateTime AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate AND IPS.Name = V.Name THEN 1
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ELSE 0 
  END = 1   
AND 
  CASE 
    WHEN V.ProgramID LIKE 'PC%' and V.ProgramID = IPS.ProgramID and IPS.Name <> V.Name THEN 0
    WHEN V.ProgramID LIKE 'PC%' and V.ProgramID = IPS.ProgramID and IPS.Name = 'N/A' THEN 0
  ELSE 1 
END = 1
```

/*Refactor*/

```
select 
   /*some columns*/
from 
  #SmallerRange IPS
  inner join #LargerRange V on V.InOrOut = IPS.InOrOut and V.LocNum = IPS.LocNum and V.AccountNumber != IPS.AccountNumber
WHERE 
  IPS.InOrOut = 'I' and
  IPS.EntryDate =  V.EntryDate
  AND IPS.OriginDate=V.OriginDate     
  AND IPS.ProgramID = V.ProgramID and not
  (V.ProgramID LIKE 'PC%' and V.ProgramID = IPS.ProgramID and IPS.Name <> V.Name and IPS.Name = 'N/A')  and not
  (V.ProgramID LIKE 'PC%' and V.ProgramID = IPS.ProgramID and IPS.Name = 'N/A')

    union all

select 
   /*some columns*/
from 
  #SmallerRange IPS
  inner join #LargerRange V on V.InOrOut = IPS.InOrOut and V.LocNum = IPS.LocNum and V.AccountNumber != IPS.AccountNumber
WHERE 
  IPS.InOrOut = 'I' and
  IPS.EntryDate =  V.EntryDate AND  
  IPS.ExitDate =  V.ExitDate AND 
  IPS.ProgramID = V.ProgramID and not
  (V.ProgramID LIKE 'PC%' and V.ProgramID = IPS.ProgramID and IPS.Name <> V.Name and IPS.Name = 'N/A') and not
  (V.ProgramID LIKE 'PC%' and V.ProgramID = IPS.ProgramID and IPS.Name = 'N/A')
```

Comment: No time ATM to double-check the logic of the refactor, but wrt “does not *seem* to be due to duplicate rows”: have you *definitely* ruled that out by using `DISTINCT` or `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`? Another trick to gather clues about logic differences after a refactor is to sort by all the output columns (add `ORDER BY <all columns>` to the before and after queries) and compare the results in a text diff tool. Note that this isn't perfect, there may be edge cases you won't catch as they are not present in your data yet, but it can sometimes highlight issues that are otherwise less visible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did test this out by selecting the results into global temp tables; one for the new query and one for the old. I then queries those two tables three times: select new except select old, select old except select new, and one with an intersect (this is how I check result set changes). When using a distinct for that first except, I was still seeing those extra rows. I was also getting extra rows when using unions instead of union alls.

Comment: @scarr030 Don't use `EXCEPT` or the old data to compare against, you may be using a predicate that is not 100% *correct* and causing the increased cardinality you're not expecting. Keep your tests / debugging simple, and just try a `SELECT YourColumns` vs `SELECT DISTINCT YourColumns` for each query on each side of the `UNION ALL`, individually, and see if the counts match or not with and without the `DISTINCT` keywords. If they don't match, then you have dupes internal to that specific query itself that were previously being filtered out.